# Adding Date and Select Field Values to Dropzone Autosubmit

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I have the following form and inputs that I am trying to use in conjunction with the Dropzone code:

```
<form action="/carrier/hr/employees/show/{{$employee->id}}/uploadAttachment" class="dropzone">
                          <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
                    <input name="employeeID" value="{{$employee->id}}" type="hidden">  
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="fallback">
                    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />  
                  </div>

                </form>
                    Date:
                    <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" id="date">
                    Due Date:
                    <input type="date" name="dueDate" class="form-control" id="dueDate">
                    Type:
                    <select id="type" class="form-control" name="type">
                        <option>Please Select</option>
                        <option value="Drivers License">Drivers License</option>
                    </select>
```

And this is currently the Dropzone-specific script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // disable auto discover
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var providerDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", { 
        paramName: 'file',
        maxFilesize: 10, // MB
        maxFiles: 20,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.xlsx,.xls",
          init: function() {
            this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("date", $('#date').val());
                formData.append("dateDue", $('#dueDate').val());
                formData.append("type", $('#type').val());
                console.log(formData)
            });
          }
    });

    providerDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(file) {
        location.reload();
    });


});
</script>
```

I would like to be able to send the date, dueDate and type fields along with all of the uploads, but unfortunately nothing except what is in the form (and the employeeID is simply a test field) is submitted.

But if I move the inputs into the form section, these fields overlap and fill the actual Dropzone area.

I believe I am close with the `init` in the Dropzone script, but for some reason none of the other fields' values are being submitted alongside the actual file upload.

I am open to anything when it comes to this.

Comment: What version of Dropzone are you using? It should work fine as you have it, at least with the lastest version, I believe it's 5.1.2

Comment: I just pulled the most recent version this morning to double check that I did in fact have a good and most recent copy but it still gives the same results. :/